# c++/gas station or petrol pump program

Tags: c++

This is the program i have phrased in turbo c++, basically i have phrased it to calculate the litres  of petrol or diesel purchased in an particular amount; the problem is that it's not showing separately for petrol and diesel, please run it and tell me what wrong i have done?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    double amount,res;
    char ch;
    cout<<"Welcome to Bharat Petroleum"<<endl;
    cout<<"Press P for Petrol and D for Diesel:"<<endl;
    cin>>ch;
    {
        if (ch=='P')
            cout<<"Enter your Amount:"<<endl;
        cin>>amount;
        res=(amount/68)*1;
        cout<<"Petrol purchased in litres:"<<endl<<res;
    }
    {
        if (ch=='D')
            cout<<"Enter your Amount:"<<endl;
        cin>>amount;
        res=(amount/48)*1;
        cout<<"Diesel purchased in litres:"<<endl<<res;
    }
    getch();
}
```

// where petrol is 68 rupees (inr) /litre and Diesel is 48//

Comment: what do you mean by `it's not showing separately for petrol and diesel`

Comment: Check your {}. They go after the if.

Comment: Have you ever heard of indentation?

Comment: run it yourself and firstly press D for diesel and than u will came to know what the problem is

Comment: i need the the program to be like, when i press D than it should ask me for diesel only, but when i am pressing D it's coming differently

Comment: Nobody here wants to save, compile and run your program; that's now how this site works. Describe your problem, don't rely on people running your program to find the problem themselves.

Answer (score 4):

Your braces are wrong, so only the first line after the `if` is bound to it. Try this:

```
if (ch=='P')
{
  cout<<"Enter your Amount:"<<endl;
  cin>>amount;
  res=(amount/68)*1;
  cout<<"Petrol purchased in litres:"<<endl<<res;
} 
else if (ch=='D')
{
  cout<<"Enter your Amount:"<<endl;
  cin>>amount;
  res=(amount/48)*1;
  cout<<"Diesel purchased in litres:"<<endl<<res;
}
```

If you want to generalize this to other types of fuel, you cound use an `std::map<std::string, double>` matching fuel type strings to prices:

```
std::map <std::string, double fuelPrices;
fuelPrices["P"] = 68.;
fuelPrices["D"] = 48.;
fuelPrices["CNG"] = ....;
```

Then, read the fuel type into a tring instead of a `char`:

```
std::string fuel;
....
cin >> fuel;
```

Then you can check if the fuel type is in the map, and take action:

```
if (fuelPrices.find(fuel) != fuelPrices.end())
{
  // fuel is in map
  cout<<"Enter your Amount:"<<endl;
  cin>>amount;
  double res=(amount/fuelPrices[fuel])*1;
  cout<< fuel << " purchased in litres:"<<endl<<res;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot it work down, thanks for your help, but if i have to add 1 more thing like CNG or something else to show differently for CNG, than i have to use if or  else if?

Comment: @aki I added a solution using an `std::map`.

Answer (score 1):

The braces are at wrong places.

The braces come for the `if` block or `else` block and not before the if or elseblock.

```
if(petrol)
{
//petrol - no of litres calculation
}
else if(diesel)
{
//diesel- no of litres calculation
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have not ran it as am currently not in a position to check. I am not sure if 'turbo' c++ has different syntax but your 'if' statements have the '{' (open scope) in the wrong place and should be on the line after the if statement:

```
{
    if (ch=='P')
          blah; // only this will be done if the statement is true
    ...
}
```

Should be:

```
if (ch=='P')
{
    ...  //Now all of the code int eh brackets will be done if the if statement is true
}
```